# Accurate scale formula for endless road

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making an endless straight road from top to bottom and using a single bitmapData for it that I use in multiple tiles. Those tiles are arranged correctly from top to bottom (let's say top to bottom of screen) by using a formula that calculates what their scale values should be. The scale value of the first tile is calculated according to its position then all other tile are calculated according to their previous tile. This works great except that when everything loops I can see the bottom tile (the first one) having its width getting slightly larger than it should (around 5 pixels too large). When that first tile goes out of screen it's sent back to the top of screen and the next tile takes the role of top tile, etc ... But because of the slight width enlargement the road has a slight jump in size when the transition occurs. So that means my formula is close but slightly wrong in calculating the scale of the first tile. What is wrong with the formula and what should be corrected?

```
var speedFactor:Number = speed / _length;//size of screen top to bottom 
var bitmap:RoadTile = tiles[0]; 
bitmap.y += speedFactor * bitmap.y; //scaled speed      
var distance:Number = _length - bitmap.y;//calculate position and determine scale           
if(distance < 0)
{
    distance = _length + Math.abs(distance);
}
else
{
    distance = bitmap.y;
}           
var scale:Number = (distance / _length);    
bitmap.scaleX = bitmap.scaleY = scale;  
//scale is calculated but is slightly wrong.
```

You can see the result here: http://angrybot.us/tests/road/

Notice the bottom of the screen where the width of the road slightly changes and then jumps back to normal when the top tile is removed and sent back to the beginning. 
I now got a better result by applying a mask but that's really just a hack. 
I also got a better result by adjusting the scale of the top tile according to the width it needs to be at the bottom of the screen. Still not perfect though.

I think I know what I'm missing and I'm gonna work on that: adding in the formula the angle of the graphic. Here the tile side have a angle of 28 (the engine works with tile of different side angle). Basically the angle needs to be added to the formula so that when the top tile moves down, its new scale is calculated according to what the tile width needs to be at the bottom of the screen (that width needs to always be the same so no jump occur in the road display)

Comment: Could post an image please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally got an accurate result:

So starting with tiles made of trapezoidal graphics and aligned from top to bottom (scale are calculated from the previous tile). To make everything loop seamlessly you need to apply trig of course. 
First calculate or define the 2 trapezoidal widths (the long one and the short one). Then using the height of the tile (no scale applied) calculate the angle of the side and the required width (the width the tile looping at the bottom of screen must always have at that position) (in my case I'm using graphics with middle registration but anything would work):

```
var base:Number = (upperWidth - lowerWidth) / 2;
var length:Number = textureData.height;         
targetAngle = Math.atan(base / length)//this is our angle                   
oppositeAngle = Math.PI / 2 - angle;//opposite angle            
var side:Number = (length / 2) / Math.tan(oppositeAngle);           
endTargetWidth = upperWidth - (side * 2)//this is the width that the top tile must always have at the bottom of the screen.
```

Next in the loop we add some speed to our top tile (whatever system you come up with but the tile has advanced a bit)

```
var tilePos:Number = tile.y;//new position
var tileScale:Number = tile.scaleX;         
var targetPos:Number = (_length - tilePos) / tileScale;// where is the tile positioned according to the length and rescaled to 1? (bottom of screen)        
var sidetarget:Number = (textureData.height / 2) + targetPos;//(since I'm using middle registration)            
var side:Number = sidetarget / Math.tan(oppositeAngle);//that's it we get the extra length at scale 1
var projectedTileWidth:Number = lowerWidth + (side * 2);// this is the width of the tile at bottom of screen at scale 1
//we know the width the tile is gonna have (at scale 1) at bottom of screen
// and we know what width we need so let's divide and get our true correct scale value      
var scale:Number = endTargetWidth / projectedTileWidth
//now we apply that to our tile and the jumping issue is gone.
```

I don't show how to align the following tiles but it's trivial since the next tile width needs to be the:  graphic width (upperWidth) * the previous tile scale